# Capture a single pixel from a fullscreen window

Tags: c, winapi

I've been looking for an answer for the past few days but I can't find one, hope you can help me.

Basically, I'm trying to make a program that launches a countdown when one specific pixel from a fullscreen program turns red. I've tried using the GetPixel() function from windows.h, but the function always returns a white pixel when an application is in fullscreen mode (255 255 255). I don't really want to use the .NET CopyFromScreen() since i haven't got a clue on how to use C++.

Here's how i use it :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "sdl.h"
#include <Windows.h>



int main(int argc, char *args[])
{
    //Variables
    COLORREF Pixel1;
    HDC handle = GetDC(NULL);
    while(1) //Using this loop for testing only
    {
        Pixel1 = GetPixel(handle, 950, 15);
        fprintf(stdout, "%d %d %d", GetRValue(Pixel1), GetGValue(Pixel1), GetBValue(Pixel1));
    }
return 0;
}
```

Is there another way to get a single pixel from a fullscreen window ?

Thanks in advance
By the way, sorry if the grammar isn't spot on, frenchie here.

EDIT : so after a few more tries, it appears that the color is in fact the color of the windows right behind the fullscreen app. So, is there a way to use GetPixel() with a fullscreen ? Am I missing something ?

Comment: Can you show the code in which you make the call to `GetPixel()`?

Comment: *"I don't really want to use the .NET CopyFromScreen() since i haven't got a clue on how to use C++"* - .NET and C++ have zero overlap. Anyway, produce a [mcve] if you want this question to turn useful.

Comment: Added the code, sorry guys. Then I don't really get the concept behind .NET. I can't use it in C only, can I ?

Comment: Per the `GetPixel()` documentation: "*The return value is the COLORREF value that specifies the RGB of the pixel. If the pixel is outside of the current clipping region, **the return value is CLR_INVALID (0xFFFFFFFF defined in Wingdi.h)**.*" If you treat `CLR_INVALID` as an RGB value, it will be interpreted as white. Check for errors before using values. You are likely misusing `GetPixel()`.

Comment: The problem is that it works with a windowed program. It gets white if a program is in fullscreen

Comment: Wait, does this work with `CopyFromScreen()`?

Comment: My guess, the "fullscreen" app is actually a DirectX app with exclusive access when fullscreen. This would mean that the display - when its fullscreen  - is not under the control of GDI.

Comment: That's right, is there another way to capture a directX app ?